# Failed to generate a user instance issue of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance

Tags: vb.net

SQL2019 / Windows 10 pro 22H2
The connection string is

```
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CustomerDb.mdf;
```

The connection is working until shutdown and reboot the PC.

Error happened while connect to the database.

The log of error is as below,

OnError, Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed. 於 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection); 於 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj); 於 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj); 於 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK); 於 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean withFailover); 於 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart); 於 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance); 於 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance); 於 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection); 於 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options); 於 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject); 於 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject); 於 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject); 於 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection); 於 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory); 於 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(); 於 MyGraphic.CMapDataCollection.DetachDatabase(String NameWithExt);

If I change the statement (remove the slash), connection work again.

```
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|CustomerDb.mdf;
```

Does anyone has same issue?